# How to implement Python's issuperset() in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

Sorry for newbie question. I try to implement Pythons `issuperset()` with Scala class

Python example:

```
 weighted_fruits_set = {"banana", "orange","apple"}
 check = {"banana"}
 weighted_fruits_set.issuperset(check)
```

Python answers :`"True"`

my Scala code below, I tried `contains` to find `superset` from list of `case class weightedFruits` and I check if string `"banana"` exists in `weightedFruits.name` :

```
object Learn extends App {


  case class weightedFruits(name:List[String], weight:Double) {
override def toString = s"name: ${name.mkString("<", ",", ">")}, weight: $weight\n"
 }

 var weightedFruitsList = new scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[weightedFruits]()

 weightedFruitsList += ( 
                     weightedFruits(List("banana","orange"),180),
                     weightedFruits(List("banana","orange","apple"),170),                                 
                     weightedFruits(List("feijoa","fig"),201),
                     weightedFruits(List("banana","apple","melon"),165)
                     )

val check = weightedFruits(List("banana"),200)                       

weightedFruitsList += check                       

val item = weightedFruitsList(1)

val bol:Boolean = item.name.contains(check.name)

println("item: "+item)
println("check: "+check)
println("bool: "+bol)

}
```

The output of my code is `false` (but must be `true`) :

```
item: name: <banana,orange,apple>, weight: 170.0

check: name: <banana>, weight: 200.0

bool: false
```

Thanks for any help. I truly hope my explanation was clear

Comment: As I understand your questions, `issuperset` means: 
`def f[A](list1: List[A], list2: List[A]): Boolean` where `true` indicates that `list1` contains all of `list2`'s elements, and `false` otherwise?

So `f(List(1,2,3), List(1)) === true`, but `f(List(1,2,3), List(4)) === false`?

Comment: `.contains` takes an element, not a list, in your case `List("banana","orange").contains(List("banana")) == false`

Answer (score 4):

The other current answers are, in my opinion, doing more than they need to. If set A is a subset of set B, then all elements of A are in B. So if we remove all elements of B from A, there should be nothing left. So

```
val a = List("banana") 
val b = List("banana", "orange","apple")
val c = List("tomato") 

(a diff b).isEmpty                                //> true
(c diff b).isEmpty                                //> false
```

(You don't specify what should happen if either "set" contains duplicates)

And if you're actually using Sets and not Lists, this operation is already in the standard library

```
def subsetOf(that: GenSet[A]): Boolean
```

> Tests whether this set is a subset of another set. that the set to
>       test. returns true if this set is a subset of that, i.e. if every
>       element of this set is also an element of that

See [Scaladoc here](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.Set@subsetOf(that:scala.collection.GenSet[A]):Boolean)

So you can convert your "sets" to actual Sets with `.toSet`, and use this

Comment: The only problem with this approach is that you create an intermediate list (hopefully empty), while in fact you only need a boolean (and behind the scene there is `HashMap`, but that part is probably unavoidable). Also it scans the whole left list even when result is already defined.

Comment: Sure, you can make it faster. But it's short, clear, and easy to demonstrate works correctly. Once the code is working correctly, and measurements show this is a significant time consumer, then it can be optimised. Also, the intermediate list is at most the length of the subset.

Comment: Thanks @The Archetypal Paul for detailed explanation and mentioning `Set`

Answer (score 2):

```
def isSuperSet[A](a: Set[A])(b: List[A]) = b.forall(a.contains(_))
```

above function returns `true` if `a` is superset of `b`

convert list of fruits to `Set` (a only) and then use this function.

Comment: You don't need `b` to be a `Set`, and even for `a` it's only important if you have long lists. The last statement is wrong, note `.name` in OP.

Comment: @VictorMoroz thanks for the suggection. edited the answer.

Comment: @VictorMoroz edited accordingly thanks for suggestion.

Comment: You don't even need  the `contains`.`a(x)` is true if `a` contains `x` and false otherwise. So it's just `b forall a` - which is how the standard library implements `subsetOf`.

Comment: Changed to Set (names of `item` and `weightedFruitsList`) , `b:Set` too ,still getting `false` after `val cont = isSuperSet(check.name)(item.name)`

Comment: @Toren, I tihnk you have the params the wrong way around. It checks `a` is a superset of `b`